Anyone know of a server that will delay icmp responses? I need a ping target that will echo reliably, but with a 1000-3000ms (or more) delay
It's weird to think anyone would need such a thing, but here I am. I'm testing a bunch of icmp tools and am having a hard time testing them without simply faking the responses and there are reasons that doing so might give me a false confirmation on my code.
I just need an icmp echo (ping) server that will reply VERY late. Anything more than 1000ms is fine. It'd be awesome if it were configurable, but I don't really need that.

You could do this with sch_netem - it lets you introduce delays or packet loss for a network interface. The command below would add a delay of 2000ms plus or minus 1000ms (so between 1000ms and 3000ms total) to eth0:
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 2000ms 1000ms

